# What causes the increase in Gradient and Total Error under Stochastic Gradient Descet mode?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, mlp

I am trying to understand the intuition behind how neural networks learn. I understand the math behind it and have already tried to solve it analytically. While coding `Multilayer Perceptron` from scratch in `Python` I face the problem of increasing total error. I have commented my code, explained the operations, and also posted resulted output and graphs of three different scenarios of training. Moreover, I have used `NumPy` vector operation whenever possible to reduce my code.

**Summary:**

- The main method contains code that generates data for binary calssification, using stochastic gradient descent methods, and Dense class objects and their methods to train model
- The network has three layers; Input (4 Nodes), Hidden Layer (6 Nodes), and Output (2 Nodes)
- The Dense class is implementation of a Layer in network

**The dense class represents a layer in `MLP Network`:**

Contains the following:

- Constructor: Which randomly initialize weights and biases
- Sigmoid method: Which activate the linear combination aka Activation potentail of the layer
- d_sigmoid method: Which find the value of first differential of the sigmoid
- forward_pass method: Which perform forward propagation of a layer
- backward_pass method: Which perform backward propagation of a layer

```py
#Importing numpy for vector operations
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(78)
class Dense():
  def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_nodes):
        
        #Weights associated with all n_nodes for n_inputs synaptic inputs
        #Each column in the weight matrix is weight vector associated with one neuron
        
        self.weights = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=n_inputs*n_nodes).reshape(n_inputs, n_nodes)
        
        #Biases associated with each neuron, shape (1, n_nodes)
        #There are n_nodes columns and each one represent bias associated with one neuron in the layer
        #This one dimension array will be added to linear combinations of all neurons  
        #assuming the synaptic connection associated with biases is '1'
        
        self.biases = np.ones(n_nodes)

    def sigmoid(self):
        #Activates the activation_potential -> ndarray
        #Save the activated ndarry to outputs, as I will need this later
        
        self.outputs = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-self.activation_potentials))
        
        return self.outputs

    def d_sigmoid(self):
        #Derivitive of the activation potential -> ndarray (For all neurons, values of first differentail activation function at activation_potential)
        #Will be used in local gradients calculation

        #Vector value of shape (n_nodes,) 
        return self.outputs * (1 - self.outputs)
        
    def forward_pass(self, inputs):
        #Calculate activation potential of the current layer neurons -> ndarray 
        #Which is inputs times weights add a bias
        #Stores it to activation_potentials
        
        self.activation_potentials = np.dot(self.weights.T, inputs) + self.biases
        
        #Return the outputs of the layer by calling sigmoid() whih activates the activation potentials
        return self.sigmoid()

    def backward_pass(self, learning_rate, inputs_to_layer, target,
                      prev_loc_grads = [], prev_weights = []):

        #The term previous layer in this method is a lyer next to current layer which made call to this method, because this bakward signal propegate from output layer to input layer

        #input_to_layer: represent ndarray of inputs to current layer which made call to this method
        #target: represent ndarray of target after one-hot-encoding it
        #prev_loc_grads: local gradients of layer next to current layer, I call it previous because this is backpropagation and the flow is propagated from output towards input layer
        #prev_weights: weights matrix of layer next to current layer, I call it previous because of backward signal flow


        #No previous local gradients means the call to backwardpass is made with output layer object
        if not len(prev_loc_grads):
            #At Output layer local gradient of each node is error at that node * derivative of activation function
            #While error at a node is (predicted - actual value)
            #Next line perform element wise subtraction of two array (the predicted and desired)
            self.error_at_end_nodes = self.outputs - target
            
            #Calculate the local gradients
            self.loc_gradients = self.error_at_end_nodes * self.d_sigmoid()
        else:
            # Local gradients of nodes in hidden layer are (derivitive of activation * sum of all (local gradients of previous layer neurons * wights associated to synaptic connection of those neurons)
         
            # Calculating the sum of all (local gradients of previous layer neurons * wights associated to synaptic connection of those neurons)
            temp = np.zeros(prev_weights.shape[0])
            for i in range(prev_loc_grads.size):
                temp += prev_loc_grads[i] * prev_weights[:, i]
            
        #Local gradients of the hidden layer
        self.loc_gradients = self.d_sigmoid() * temp
            
        #Update Weights, based on learning rate, local gradients and inputs to layer
        self.weights = self.weights + (learning_rate * np.outer(inputs_to_layer, self.loc_gradients))
        
        # The inputs_to_layer is ommited as bias is (conceptually) multiplied by input from a neuron with a fixed activation of 1
        self.biases = self.biases + learning_rate * self.loc_gradients


        return self.weights, self.biases
```

The main code which contains training loop and training data:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dense import Dense
import numpy as np
import random


def main():
    print("In Main .. Starting ..")
    
    #Generating Data with 10 samples containing 4 features and one target (binary classification)
    data = make_classification(n_samples=10, n_features=4, n_classes=2)

    
    X_train = data[0]
    y_train = data[1]

    #Normalizing the data
    X_train = X_train/X_train.max()
    
    print('Training Data: (X) : ', X_train)
    print('Taraining Data: (y): ', y_train)
    
    #Encoding data using one hot encoding technique 
    enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)
    desired = enc.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
    print("Targets after One Hot Encoding: ", desired)
    

    #-------------------------------Experimental Code-----------------------------------------
    
    #netwok is a list of all layers in the network, each time a layer is created as Dense() object, will be appended to network
    network = []
    print("----------------------------Layer 1-------------------------")
    network.append(Dense(4,6))
    print('Created Only Hidden Layer: N_nodes: {} , N_inputs: {}'.format(6,4))
    print("----------------------------Layer 2-------------------------")
    network.append(Dense(6,2)) 
    print('Created Output Layer: N_nodes: {} , N_inputs: {}'.format(2,6))    
    
    epoch = 1
    error = []
    
    #The main training loop, exits at after 10 epochs
    while epoch <= 10:
        
        #Random suffling of training data
        temp = list(zip(X_train,y_train))
        random.shuffle(temp)
        X_train,y_train=zip(*temp)

        #Variabels to store  the temporary state of the operations
        weights = 0
        biases = 0
        
        #List to store the intermediate weights and biases for means square error calculation at end of each epoch
        wb = []

        print('--------------------------Epoch: {}-------------------------'.format(epoch), '\n')
        
        #Select one feature vector from feature matrix and corresponding target vector from desired matrix (Which was obtained from one hot encoding)
        for x,y in zip(X_train, desired):     
            
            #previous_inputs list keeps track of inputs from layer to layer in each epoch
            previous_inputs = []    
            
            #At start of each epoch, the list contains only inputs from input nodes which are the features of current training sample
            previous_inputs.append(x)

            #This loop iterates over all layers in network and perform forward pass
            for layer in network:
                #Forward_pass perform forward propagation of a layer of last element of the previous_inputs list, 
                #and returns the output of layer which is stored as ndarray in list, as it will be used as inputs to next layer
                previous_inputs.append(layer.forward_pass(previous_inputs[-1]))

            #Ignore the output of last layer, as I'm using the preious_inputs array in reverse order in backward_pass in next loop
            previous_inputs = previous_inputs[:-1]

            #Next loop reverses the network and previous_inputs lists to perform  backward propagation of al layers from output layer all the way to input layer
            for layer, inputs in zip(network[::-1], previous_inputs[::-1]):
                
                #If the layer is not output layer then perform backward propagation using code inside if statement
                if layer != network[-1]:
                    
                    #call to backward_pass using learning rate = 0.0001, inputs to current layer, target vector 'y', 
                    #previous_loc_gradients (local gradients of layer next to current layer),
                    #and prev_weights (weights of layer next to current layer) 
                    #Store the updated weights and biases for mean square error calculation at end of epoch
                    weights, biases = layer.backward_pass(0.0001, prev_inputs, y, prev_loc_gradients, prev_weights)
                
                #otherwise, perform the backward pass for output layer using code in else block
                else:
                    weights, biases = layer.backward_pass(0.0001, prev_inputs, y)
                
                #Store local gradietns nad weights of current layer for next layer backward pass
                prev_loc_gradients = layer.loc_gradients
                prev_weights = layer.weights
                
                #Add updated weights and biases to wb, will be using it in next loop
                wb.append((weights, biases))
            
            #error_i is sum of errors for all training examples on updated weights and biases
            error_i = 0
            
            #This loop calculates Total Error on new weights and biases, by considering the whole training data
            for x_val, y_val in zip(X_train, desired):
                
                previous_inputs = []    
                previous_inputs.append(x_val)
                
                #Perform  forward pass on new weights and biases
                for layer in network:
                    #Forward Pass
                    previous_inputs.append(layer.forward_pass(previous_inputs[-1]))
                
                #add the error of prediction of current training sample to prevoius errors
                error_i += np.power((previous_inputs[-1] - y_val), 2).sum()
            
            #Append total error of current sample to error list, and repeate the process for next sample, do this for all samples
            error.append(error_i)
        
        #Increase epoch by one, and perform forward, backward on next sample, and calculate error for all samples, do this until while  is true
        epoch += 1
    
    #Plot the errors after training completes, 
    plt.plot(error)
    plt.show()
    #-------------------------------Experimental Code-----------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**At the end I get these outputs and graphs depending on epochs and training data size:**

- For 1 epoch and 10 training samples

```
In Main .. Starting ..
Training Data: (X) :  [[-0.26390333 -0.12430637 -0.38741338  0.20075948]
 [ 0.63580037 -1.05223163 -0.58551008  0.68911107]
 [-0.54448011  0.08334418 -0.4174701   0.11937366]
 [ 0.22123838 -0.54513245 -0.40486294  0.39508491]
 [-0.3489578  -0.2067747  -0.55992358  0.30225496]
 [ 0.46346633  0.29702914  0.76883225 -0.42087526]
 [ 0.05631264  0.04373764  0.10200898 -0.05777301]
 [ 0.19738736 -0.26007568 -0.10694419  0.15615838]
 [ 0.12548086 -0.17220663 -0.07570972  0.10523554]
 [-0.52398487  1.          0.63178402 -0.68315832]]
Taraining Data: (y):  [0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
Targets after One Hot Encoding: [[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
----------------------------Layer 1-------------------------
Created Only Hidden Layer: N_nodes: 6 , N_inputs: 4
----------------------------Layer 2-------------------------
Created Output Layer: N_nodes: 2 , N_inputs: 6
--------------------------Epoch: 1-------------------------
```

[image: For 1 epoch and 10 training samples]

- For 10 epochs and 10 training sample

```
In Main .. Starting ..
Training Data: (X) :  [[-0.26390333 -0.12430637 -0.38741338  0.20075948]
 [ 0.63580037 -1.05223163 -0.58551008  0.68911107]
 [-0.54448011  0.08334418 -0.4174701   0.11937366]
 [ 0.22123838 -0.54513245 -0.40486294  0.39508491]
 [-0.3489578  -0.2067747  -0.55992358  0.30225496]
 [ 0.46346633  0.29702914  0.76883225 -0.42087526]
 [ 0.05631264  0.04373764  0.10200898 -0.05777301]
 [ 0.19738736 -0.26007568 -0.10694419  0.15615838]
 [ 0.12548086 -0.17220663 -0.07570972  0.10523554]
 [-0.52398487  1.          0.63178402 -0.68315832]]
Taraining Data: (y):  [0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
Targets after One Hot Encoding: [[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
----------------------------Layer 1-------------------------
Created Only Hidden Layer: N_nodes: 6 , N_inputs: 4
----------------------------Layer 2-------------------------
Created Output Layer: N_nodes: 2 , N_inputs: 6
--------------------------Epoch: 1-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 2-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 3-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 4-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 5-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 6-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 7-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 8-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 9-------------------------

--------------------------Epoch: 10-------------------------
```

[image: For 10 epochs and 10 training smaples]

- For 50 epochs and 1000 samples

```
In Main .. Starting ..
Training Data: (X) :  [[ 0.10845729  0.03110484 -0.10935314 -0.01435112]
 [-0.27863109 -0.17048214 -0.04769305  0.04802046]
 [-0.10521553 -0.07933533 -0.07228399  0.01997508]
 ...
 [-0.25583767 -0.24504791 -0.36494096  0.0549903 ]
 [ 0.06933997 -0.29438308 -1.21018002  0.02951967]
 [-0.02084834  0.06847175  0.29115171 -0.00640819]]
Taraining Data: (y):  [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0]
Targets after One Hot Encoding: [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
----------------------------Layer 1-------------------------
Created Only Hidden Layer: N_nodes: 6 , N_inputs: 4
----------------------------Layer 2-------------------------
Created Output Layer: N_nodes: 2 , N_inputs: 6
--------------------------Epoch: 1------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 2------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 3------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 4------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 5------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 6------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 7------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 8------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 9------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 10------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 11------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 12------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 13------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 14------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 15------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 16------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 17------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 18------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 19------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 20------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 21------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 22------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 23------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 24------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 25------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 26------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 27------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 28------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 29------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 30------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 31------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 32------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 33------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 34------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 35------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 36------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 37------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 38------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 39------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 40------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 41------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 42------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 43------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 44------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 45------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 46------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 47------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 48------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 49------------------------- 

--------------------------Epoch: 50-------------------------
```

[image: For 50 epochs and 1000 samples]

I do not understand what causes the increase in error, as the goal is to decrease it. What am I missing?

Comment: *... as it should be decreasing* is not necessarily true. loss increase means your network is divergent.

Comment: Yes, but the goal is to decrease the error in order to travel downhill to the minimal point. What I do not understand is what factor causing my network to diverge?

Comment: There are whole bunch of things people are researching to do what you ask in general settings, and it's essentially the holy grail of AI. A lot of things can affect the convergence of the network that you can tackle: network structure, activation functions, learning rate, initialization, optimization algorithm,...

Comment: have you tried gradient checking. it is better to do gradient checking for few epochs to make sure the backprop implementation is correct. You can refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrzApibhohY

Comment: I guess error is in `self.weights = self.weights + (learning_rate * np.outer(inputs_to_layer, self.loc_gradients))`. You need to subtract the gradients from the weights like `w := w-learning_rate*gradients`. If you add gradients to the weights then the cost will increase.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for pointing it out @LMKR . I was traveling uphill because of `self.error_at_end_nodes = self.outputs - target` which I changed to `self.error_at_end_nodes = target - self.outputs`.


The sign is still `+` as I'm getting explicit `-` sign from the error which adds `descending` behaviour  to the update  term.  But my cost do not fall decrease 50, which I do not understand why?